# How to implement pixel Within shape algorithm in javascript

Tags: javascript, coordinates, pixel, shapes

I am now writing a script that detect whether a pixel is within specified pixel array (shape boundary) as in figure.

```
    var shape=[
         {x:3,y:1},
         {x:4,y:1},
         {x:5,y:1},
         {x:6,y:1},
         {x:7,y:1},
         {x:7,y:2},
         {x:6,y:3},
         {x:5,y:4},
         {x:6,y:5},
         {x:7,y:6},
         {x:8,y:6},
         {x:8,y:5},
         {x:8,y:4},
         {x:8,y:3},
         {x:9,y:2},
         {x:9,y:1}
       ];

    var pixel={x:3,y:3}; //dynamic coordinate value from mouse event
   for(var i in shape){
         //check pixel whether within shape or outside
    }
```

I think there may be simpler implementation in javaScript, please let me know if any.
Thanks alot.

[image: Finding pixel within a shape]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function seems to do the trick:

```
function isPointInPoly(poly, pt){
    for(var c = false, i = -1, l = poly.length, j = l - 1; ++i < l; j = i)
        ((poly[i].y <= pt.y && pt.y < poly[j].y) || (poly[j].y <= pt.y && pt.y < poly[i].y))
        && (pt.x < (poly[j].x - poly[i].x) * (pt.y - poly[i].y) / (poly[j].y - poly[i].y) + poly[i].x)
        && (c = !c);
    return c;
}
```

From: http://jsfromhell.com/math/is-point-in-poly

Example:

```js
var shape=[
    {x:3,y:1},
    {x:4,y:1},
    {x:5,y:1},
    {x:6,y:1},
    {x:7,y:1},
    {x:7,y:2},
    {x:6,y:3},
    {x:5,y:4},
    {x:6,y:5},
    {x:7,y:6},
    {x:8,y:6},
    {x:8,y:5},
    {x:8,y:4},
    {x:8,y:3},
    {x:9,y:2},
    {x:9,y:1}
];

var p1 = {x:1, y:2};
var p2 = {x:6, y:3};
var p1in = isPointInPoly(shape, p1);
var p2in = isPointInPoly(shape, p2);
alert(p1in + ', ' + p2in);

function isPointInPoly(poly, pt){
    for(var c = false, i = -1, l = poly.length, j = l - 1; ++i < l; j = i)
        ((poly[i].y <= pt.y && pt.y < poly[j].y) || (poly[j].y <= pt.y && pt.y < poly[i].y))
        && (pt.x < (poly[j].x - poly[i].x) * (pt.y - poly[i].y) / (poly[j].y - poly[i].y) + poly[i].x)
        && (c = !c);
    return c;
}
```